# How can I find a character with specific criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to loop through a string and find a character that is not a letter or number or _ . @. This my code:

```
mystr = "saddas das"
for x in range(0, len(mystr)):
    if not(mystr[x].isdigit() or mystr[x].isalpha or mystr[x]=="@" or mystr[x]=="_" or mystr[x]=="."):
        print (x)
```

Unfortunately it doen't detect anthing while it should return the index of the space.

Comment: have you tried using regex (the python library re)

Comment: This is probably a case where a regular expression is useful; have you looked into those?

Comment: `isalpha` is a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for x in range(0, len(mystr)):
    if not(mystr[x].isdigit() or mystr[x].isalpha() or mystr[x]=="@" or mystr[x]=="_" or mystr[x]=="."):
        print (x)
```

You forgot to add `()`: `mystr[x].isalpha`. To call function you should do `mystr[x].isalpha()`. `mystr[x].isalpha` is always evaluated to `True`, that's why your code doesn't print anything

Comment: They're parenthesis, not braces.

Comment: so silly of me but i wasn't getting an error for some reason. Anyways should I delete this because it wasn't really a problem?

Comment: No, probably it will be useful for someone. This kind of error is difficult to catch sometimes...

Answer (score 3):

Use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) wich returns the pos and the character you iterate:

```
mystr = "saddas das"
for pos,c in enumerate(mystr):
    # change your conditions to make it easier to understand, isalpha() helps
    if c.isdigit() or c.isalpha() or c in "@_.":
        continue # do nothing
    else:
        print (pos)
```

Output:

```
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('[^\d\w\.@]')
s = "saddas das"

for match in pattern.finditer(s):
    print(match.start())
```

**Output**

```
6
```

The pattern `'[^\d\w\.@]'` matches everything that is not a digit, not a letter, nor `_`, `.` or `@`.